# Changes not reflected in xml file C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox,from where you select a name(this is the name of a screen whose details are saved in an xml file).

To delete this screen from the xml file I use this value to delete the screen(with reference to the Name attribute or the screen tag)

My delete codes are as

```
XmlDocument docc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
docc.Load("test.xml");
System.Xml.XmlNodeList list = docc.GetElementsByTagName("Screen");
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in list)
{
    if (node.Attributes["Name"].Value == comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())
    {
        node.RemoveChild(node);
    }
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Screen has been deleted.");
    if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    docc.Save("test.xml");
    break;
}
```

The problem that I am getting is that only the first item that is,the selected by default in the combobox is deleted.

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` at the end of your foreach loop effectively makes your loop run only once. 
What you probably want is the following

```
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in list)
{
    if (node.Attributes["Name"].Value == comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())
    {
         node.RemoveChild(node);

         System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Screen has been deleted.");
         if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
         {
             comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
             comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
         }
         docc.Save("test.xml");
         break; // break now only if the node is the expected one. 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also change the for loop to something like :

```
var node = from node in list 
            where node.Attributes["Name"].Value == comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()
            select node;

// if you expect one run this, otherwise, put it in a foreach 
node.RemoveChild(node);       

 // the rest...
```

and let linq worry about the matching ...

Comment: `node.RemoveChild(node);` wont compile

Comment: That may work or fail am not sure. but in your code `node` is a sequence. `RemoveChild` is not taking sequence as parameter. Am I right?

Comment: I believe there should be only 1 there, hence my comment just above that line ... I'm sure he'll let us know if it doesn't work ...